# Service for feed converting (version problem)

Tags: .net, rss, feed

I have made an application (for my self) for feeds reading, using **[SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx)**,
  and the problem is that it supports just Atom 1.0 and RSS 2.0.

I have bunch of feeds which are RSS 0.92 version and so...

So my question is: Is there any service which I can use for converting RSS 0.92 to RSS 2.0 or Atom 1.0.
Someone told me that I should use [**feedburner**](http://feedburner.google.com), but I could not find there how to do that. :)

Comment: I always thought that FeedBurner would convert all incomming feeds to something like RSS 2.0 or Atom 1.0... Weird...

Comment: I could not find there anything like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com).  Use a trivial pipe like http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=PicO8ejT3BG6sr1Uy6ky6g , except that your source feeds would
 be RSS 0.92.  Either way, you just pipe everything back out, then use a URL like http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=PicO8ejT3BG6sr1Uy6ky6g&_render=rss&atom_feed_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fatomfeed (note the render=rss) to serialize it back out to RSS 2 (or Atom if you choose).

EDIT: Actually, it looks like [FeedBurner](http://feedburner.com) can convert to Atom just fine.  Go to http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/myfeeds , login, and you should see a box that says "Burn a feed right this instant".  Enter the RSS .92 URL, then you'll have to choose a FeedBurner code, such as foo/bar.  Finally, you can use Atom urls like http://feeds2.feedburner.com/foo/bar?format=xml .  I have not figured out how to use FeedBurner to convert to RSS 2.

Comment: thanks very much, actually I already find out yahoo pipes very interesting thing :) and it kinda works :)

Answer (score 0):

Would something like [FeedKiller](http://www.feedkiller.com/) work for you?